# i am trying to figure out how to count only the nodes width a specific value in xml

Tags: c#, xml

```
    public int getWins()
    {
        List<string> matchesAsList = new List<string>();

        XmlNodeList matches = _xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Matches/Match/Winner");

        foreach (XmlNode node in matches)
        {
            if (node.InnerText.ToString() = "OUR TEAM") //<- i cant figure this out
            {
                matchesAsList.Add(node.InnerText); 
            }
        }

        int Wins = matchesAsList.Count();

        return Wins;
    }
```

> I have bin having some problems with this code, iam trying to get my if to work so that it will only count the nodes of my code "where there is "OUR TEAM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` used for affectation
`==` used for test.
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#equality-operator-)

1 - You could change `node.InnerText.ToString() = "OUR TEAM"` to `node.InnerText.ToString() == "OUR TEAM"`.

```
if (node.InnerText == "OUR TEAM")
{
    matchesAsList.Add(node.InnerText); 
}
```

Note That, `Innertext` is already `string`, you don't need to call `.ToString()`.

2 - You can also use [**Equals**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_) and ignore case, like :

```
if (node.InnerText.Equals("OUR TEAM", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    matchesAsList.Add(node.InnerText); 
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: It might be also helpful to say that string comparison is case sensitive by default, so it compares exactly the given string. Example: A node containing "Our Team" or "OuR tEaM" will not match with "OUR TEAM".

Comment: @rekcul yes updated, we can use `equals` and ignore case, but i think the OP has copied the value from the XML.